# How to set a decorator on a method that is not a nestjs route

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator

NestJS

Hello! I have a problem. I want to put a decorator on a function that is not an endpoint, that is, a route.

An example of what I want to do:

```
class Controller {
      
  @Get('/')
    firstMethod() {
    secondMethod()
  }
      
  @Decorator()
    secondMethod() {}
  }
```

I want that when the `secondMethod` method is called, it will go through the Decorator

How can I do it? Thanks!

Translated with google translate

Comment: What does this decorator do?

Comment: This is a custom decorator.

I don't think it matters, but this decorator implements the role model. Due to its specifics, it should be exactly where I put it. Putting it before firstMethod doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would matter if it's on the first method or not. Can you show the decorator implementation? It might help

Comment: When the application starts, the available routes are initialized. This decorator implements a complex role model. I can grant or deny access to routes for one, several or groups of users.

Comment: I made a single entry point for requesting different data depending on the set of query parameters different functions are called. Each function inside is a separate route that my decorator should be assigned to.

Comment: Ок. [link](https://postimg.cc/k2wz9MJv) This is how the decorator is used. Endpoints are initialized when the application starts.[link](https://postimg.cc/ZWKtGJD8) This is what the decorator looks like inside.

Comment: The custom decorator uses the nestjs built-in useguards decorator

Comment: That's fine. It's all metadata, they shouldn't be interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after seeing your conversation in Discord and the [issue you opened](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/8270) I understand the request a bit better now. In short, you can't really just call a method and expect the nest enhancer to work. All that nest's `@Use*()` decorators do is set up metadata that gets read during the route initialization and the enhancers get bound to the route handlers then. As the method you're trying to work with isn't a route handler, it's not possible to send a request to that route and have t go through the enhancers, and this is due to Nest needing to have control of the request when it goes through and comes out of the request. It's just how the system is designed. You could try calling the enhancer directly, but that would most likely get complex and ugly.

Comment: I gave up on this idea and came up with another working option. I transferred everything that was in the function that "redirects" the request to the middleware, which, depending on which function needs to be called, changes the path. As a result, the changed path gets to the controller. For each individual function, I put a built-in Get decorator, because of this, now my custom decorator works as it should.

Problem solved! Thanks!